# AVR Microcontroller temp sensor communication over LAN

Tags: java, android, server, avr, lan

Hello infinitely more skilled people than me ;-),

I have a question for my Brothers School project and I want to help him.
He has a micro-controller board with a `LAN` port and wants to attach a temperature Reader to it.
Has anyone a Suggestion on **How to communicate this data let's say for example to an `Android` app that can Display the temperature graph or just the temp at the current Moment?** 
If not Android he wants to Display it via a Java app on a desktop that displays a temp graph and average temps.
I tried to Google it but I haven't found anything that describes this case. Maybe I don't know how to formulate it.
I know it super vague to describe it but maybe some nice guy can send me code example how it would look like, since I am a total beginner.
Here is the `AVR` board (it has a LAN port)

http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/MTQ5OTgxOTk-/Bausaetze_Module/Bausaetze/Bausatz_AVR_NET_IO.html

Thank you :)

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: You'll find significantly more help if you post what efforts you've taken.

Comment: "for my Brothers School project" ... "maybe some nice guy can send me code" - Is that part of your brother's project? I mean, shouldn't he be doing a project by himself, instead of asking his brother to ask other people for code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the board features an `ATmega32` controller and an `ENC28J60` *Ethernet* controller (with `SPI`!).
It seems they provide some sort of `server` application that communicates with the board (via *Ethernet/LAN*). The app is not trivial, as I see it also has firmware update feature (so the `AVR` chip has also a *bootloader* in its flash).
Anyway, an interesting approach would be to connect your `temperature sensor` on one `analog input`, then start the board and the `net-server` app (connected to *LAN*). You'll see the related measurements on some `ADCx` (in Volts).
After that, using `Wire-Shark` or similar tool, you could spy the communication messages between the board and the `server` (knowing their *IPs*, to filter out all other crap lurking on the *LAN*).
Next step would be to find out the specific message `server` sends to request the `ADCx`, and also the related answer from the board. Not trivial, yet doable I guess :)
Finally, knowing what messages are exchanged (I here assume you don't have the specs for the protocol or the source code), you should replicate/implement something similar in your `Windows`/`Android` application (further conversion from `voltage` to °C `temperature` to be displayed is yet another thing to be done by your app - the easiest part, I suppose :).
With the data you provided, I think this is the best suggestion I can make.

*Best luck with your project!*

**BTW**: Best place where you can find help (and source code examples, compilers and related stuff) for `AVR` is: [www.avrfreaks.net](http://avrfreaks.net)

Comment: Thanks you so far, is there no other way to find out how the temp string is formatted?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576215/sending-a-string-using-java-from-pc-to-board-having-microcontroller-connected-th
Is this a solution to solve the communication problem?

Comment: There are several possibilities to find out the message format: 1) using the communication protocol documentation (if available from the board seller); 2) analyzing the source code (if provided by the seller); 3) if first two are not available, then the only way to discover the messages exchanged between the board and the server is to spy the communication between them using `Wire-Shark` or similar tool (kind of reverse-engineering, but not very difficult). For the second question: I'm not a Java programmer, yet it looks like a starting point, at least it worth a try.

Comment: The idea is that you need a UDP or TCP client socket that connects to the board and send a command and then receives the answer. If it doesn't work or you encounter difficulties, then you may start another Java related question so other people that know Java well can help you. Remember one thing: more details (input) you provide, better answers (help) you will receive! :)

Comment: Even if the PC app name is `Net-Server`, having `Connect` and `Disconnect` buttons suggests that it implements a TCP or UDP client. Yet, it is possible the other way around: i.e. the board acting like a client that connects to the PC app (on a TCP port the PC app is listening on) in order to send data at a certain rate (let's say once per second)...

Comment: Thank you guys, you are awesome.
A dumb question is the avr net io to be programmed in C or Java?

Comment: The board itself is driven by an ATmega32. It is an AVR 8-bit controller made by Atmel. In more than 90% situations I've seen, the firmware is written in C. There are other possibilities I have seen rarely: assembly language, Bascom (a flavor of Basic), etc. Yet, I must confess I've never seen Java-written firmware for Atmel AVR. I'm not saying it's impossible. But AFAIK, AVRs were designed for C mainly.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you have been a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the software and firmware that comes with the board (download...)?

It pretty much has everything you'd need, i.e. TCP/IP stack, simple command/response server to access digital and analog IOs &c.

See the documentation: https://www.pollin.de/shop/downloads/D810058B.PDF, esp. "Protokollaufbau und Kommandos AVR-NET-IO", e.g. "GETADC 3 (ruft den akt. Wert des ADC-Eingangs 3 ab)"

Hence, you should be able to use the stock firmware and talk to it from your app/whatever via simple commands over TCP. You can query the boards input states and do any calculations on that in the app before displaying the result.
(**Edit**: You did not state what kind of sensor he wants to use. If the sensor's output is not an analog voltage but some digital protocol, the stock firmware in fact won't get you far.)

The boards firmware is written in C (closed source, I believe), but as I said, you'd probably not have to bother with that. However, if you want, there are alternative firmware versions available as open source from the 'net; and if you're inclined to a greater experience, you can also create your own, possibly building on an available TCP/IP stack and ENC28J60 libraries (readily available too). You could also add a simple HTTP server on top of that &c, &c.

Some links that instantly turned up when I googled for "avr net io firmware":

http://www.fhemwiki.de/wiki/AVR-NET-IO

http://engelhuber.de/blog/2013/10/29/pollin-avr-net-io-mit-e2000-firmware-ueber-php-ansteuern/

http://netio.davideickhoff.de/de/

http://son.ffdf-clan.de/